# Python: '>' not supported between instances of 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int'?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got this error
 "'>' not supported between instances of 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int'"

at the second  line using python 3 (assert len > 0)

```
def UnpackVariable(var, num):
 assert len > 0
 if type(var) is list and len(var) == num:
    return var
 else:
     ret = []
     if type(var) is list:
         assert len(var) == 1
         for i in xrange(0, num):
         ret.append(var[0])
     else:
         for i in xrange(0, num):
         ret.append(var)
 return ret
```

Comment: `len` is a function that you are tying to compare with `int`

Comment: `len` is a function, not a variable

Comment: Use `isinstance(var, list)` instead of `type`; this will word for values of `var` that instances of subclasses of `list` as well.

Comment: Also, you only reach the first `else` clause if `type(var)` is *not* `list`, so there's no need to check again (or assume that it could ever be true).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`len` is the name of built in function.

Perhaps you want to use `len(var)`

Also, I can suggest to replace

```
type(var) is list
```

with

```
isinstance(var, list)
```

And check indentation after `for`, next line should be indented more.